# In Android Studio 3.1.4, I checked `Enable Embedded Maven Repository` check box, now I've installed Android Studio 3.6.1, where can I find

Tags: android

In Android Studio 3.1.4,
I checked `Enable Embedded Maven Repository` check box under **Build => Gradle => Android Studio**

Now I've installed Android Studio 3.6.1 which is the latest Update

Where can I find `Enable Embedded Maven Repository` check box?

Comment: you found anything?

Comment: Did you find it ? If yes, please share the answer. Looks like it has been removed in the latest version of android studio. I'm using Android Studio version 4.1. I could not find it.